# Get ValueMember And DisplayMember For CheckListBox In Datagriview

Tags: c#

I Fill Check List Box From Database Using Store Procedure Like This:

I am Trying To Get The Display Member And The Value Member For The Checked Items Only And Put Them In Data Grid View.

But The Value Member Show For The First Checked Item Only And The Display Member Show The Store Procedure Name

Is There Any One Can Help

```
`int id3 = Convert.ToInt32(cbx_MainItemFilter.SelectedValue);
            int id4 = Convert.ToInt32(cbx_MainCostDriver.SelectedValue);
            var q3 = db.SP_SelectDriverItem().Where(s => s.MainCostDriverID == id4 && 
            s.MainCostItemID == id3);

            clb_SubItems.DataSource = q3.ToList();
            clb_SubItems.DisplayMember = "SubCostItemName";
            clb_SubItems.ValueMember = "SubCostItemID";`
```

private void btn_ShowDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
        for (int i = 0; i < clb_SubItems.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (clb_SubItems.GetItemChecked(i))
            {
                dgv_BOQItems.Rows.Add(clb_SubItems.Items[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have to ask, what type of app is this? Winforms? WPF? Other?

Comment: it is Winforms Application

Comment: What does `q3` contain? What does that list hold? You get no errors? Are you sure the `DisplayMember` name is correct?

Comment: q3 Contains Columns From Database And There Is No Errors And It Already Filled The CheckListBox But When I Tried To Get The ValueMember And The DisplayMember From The CheckListBox It Cause This Problem

Comment: Well where is the code that is trying to get those values?

Comment: I Added It To The Post

Comment: What fields are in the list `q3.ToList()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider loading data from your database into a list, in the class override `ToString` to what column/property you want to show in the CheckedListBox.

Simple example use the following class.

```
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => Name;
}
```

Keeping simple, use mocked data which in your case comes from your stored procedure.

```
public class Mocked
{
    public static List<Company> Companies => new List<Company>()
    {
        new Company() {Id = 1, Name = "A"},
        new Company() {Id = 2, Name = "B"},
        new Company() {Id = 3, Name = "C"},
    };
}
```

[image]

In your form, assign the DataSource for the CheckedListBox to the mocked data above in say form Shown event or button click.

```
checkedListBox1.DataSource = Mocked.Companies;
```

Language extension to use in the next code block

```
public static class CheckedListBoxExtensions
{
    public static List<Company> CheckedList(this CheckedListBox source)
        => source.Items.Cast<Company>()
            .Where((item, index) => source.GetItemChecked(index))
            .Select(item => item)
            .ToList();
}
```

Get checked items, here in a button click event, here we have access to all checked items.

```
private void CheckedCompanyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var result = checkedListBox1.CheckedList();

    if (result.Count <= 0) return;
    foreach (var company in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{company.Id, -5}{company.Name}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your help i Got A solution for This But It Still Has Simple Problem That It Duplicate The Result

```
private void btn_ShowDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < clb_SubItems.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (clb_SubItems.GetItemChecked(i))
            {

                foreach (var item in clb_SubItems.CheckedItems.OfType<SP_SelectDriverItem_Result>())
                {
                    dgv_BOQItems.Rows.Add( clb_SubItems.GetItemText(clb_SubItems.Items[i]), item.SubCostItemID);
                }
                               
            }
        }
    }
```